# How can I have a responsive height with absolutley position child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have made a very basic quote "carousel" to display customer quotes on a website by making the elements visible one at a time.

The quotes are absolutely positioned inside a container over each other then made visible accordingly. How can i make the parent container the height of the tallest quote (plus padding) without having to put a fixed pixel height on the container as technically the parent container is now empty. with css only.

```
<div class="parent-container">
    <div class="quote child-element">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="quote child-element">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="quote child-element">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

I will be adding media query breakpoints for the text at a later stage.

https://jsfiddle.net/vkchxz3q/

Comment: Basically NO. Not with CSS. Absolutely position children are removed from the flow and so do not contribute to the height/width of the parent.

Comment: What do you think the best approach would be then? either 1. Changing the child elements to float instead of being absolutely positioned then change the js accordingly or 2. measure the quote heights with js and apply it to the parent container, bearing in mind this function will have to run on window resize

Comment: Could you not `display: flex` the container then all the children grow to the height of the tallest?

Comment: Are all the quotes potentially different heights? I'm trying to figure out why you don't want to manually set a height on the container. Won't that mean that the content below your carousel will be bouncing up and down like a yoyo as the quote lengths change? That's... a little disconcerting for your users, not to mention poor UI design to have something move from under your cursor when you're clicking on it.

Comment: yes they will all be different heights depending on how many characters are in the quote. because if i set a static height then i have to change the height with media breakpoints depending on browser widths. the content below will not bounce up and down if the height of the container is set to accommodate the largest quote. the quotes are never taken away just made visible and not-visible using opacity and visibility see the .active class in the jsfiddle

Comment: @navigator instead of editing your question, create an answer yourself and put it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution using **float: left;** instead of **position: absolute;** and applying **margin-right: -100%;** see jsfiddle.

```
#fader{
    position: relative;
}

.quote{
    float: left;
    margin-right: -100%;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vkchxz3q/45/

Thanks for the suggestions and help.

*Would be nice to include some vertical alignment in a future revision, please feel free to update the jsfiddle*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to have the text center vertically in a fixed height. To do this you can use the table property for display with vertical align, browser support ->
http://caniuse.com/#search=css-table

```
#fader {
    display: table;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vkchxz3q/31/

To make the height dynamic just take away the height on #fader
https://jsfiddle.net/vkchxz3q/33/

Comment: That does not make the height dynamic.

Comment: Okay well just take away the height property on #fader, simple as that.

Comment: Now `#quote-container` just takes up the height of the displayed quote, not the tallest quote.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove `position:absolute;`, then work out what height the container should be, and the apply absolute positioning in your interval.

https://jsfiddle.net/vkchxz3q/35/

```js
var s, q, l;

s = $('#fader');
q = s.children('blockquote');
l = q.length;

var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  q.eq(i).removeClass('active');
  i == l - 1 ? i = 0 : i++;
  q.eq(i).addClass('active').css('position', 'absolute');
}, 10000);

var intHeight = 0;
q.each(function() {
  if ($(this).outerHeight() > intHeight) {
    intHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  }
});
$('#quote-container').height(intHeight);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#quote-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  height: 300px;
  /* Definative Height */
  background: #353535;
}
#fader {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
blockquote {
  visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
blockquote span {
  display: block;
  font-size: .6em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quote-container">
  <div id="fader">
    <blockquote class="active">Sometimes it is better to just walk away from things and go back to them later when you’re in a better frame of mind. <span>- Joe Blogs, Blogs Incorperated</span>

    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>If you like tuna and tomato sauce- try combining the two. It’s really not as bad as it sounds. <span>- John Smith, Kansas Kyak Club</span>

    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>Last Friday in three week’s time I saw a spotted striped blue worm shake hands with a legless lizard. <span>- Jon Doe , Riverford Farm</span>

    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also make sure that you call the height calculation processes when the element is resized in addition to upon the page loading; otherwise, a blockquote might have a height different from what the script accounts it.

Comment: @BlueSheep If it's an adaptive layout, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Make all of the elements have a great negative `margin-left` when they're not `.active` and float to one side instead of using absolute positioning. Then give their container, `#quote-container`, `overflow: auto;` to make it account for floating elements' height.

https://jsfiddle.net/vkchxz3q/36/